# How to use is_unique form validation within a specific range of record?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table called `participants`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participants` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `personal_number` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tournament_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `time_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `time_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `city_id` (`city_id`),
  KEY `tournament_id` (`tournament_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The rule for creating participants is **each** registered email address can only participate in **one** tournament (foreign key `tournament_id`); therefore **two** records with the same email address **but different** `tournament_id` should be **allowed**.

Is `is_unique` form validation able to do this operation? Or should I create a callback or a helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_unique` is just a short name for `value_does_not_already_exists_in_a_single_column`.

So, no - it won't do the job; you'll need a callback.